# In Swift, How do I use an associatedtype in a Generic Class where the type parameter is constrained by the protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

In Swift, I've got a protocol like this:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T
    func f(val:T)
}
```

I want to define a class like this:

```
class B<X:P> {
}
```

And then use the `associatedtype` T within the class B.

I've tried this:

```
class B<X:P> {
    var v:T // compiler says "Use of undeclared type"

    init() {
    }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
class B<X:P, Y> {
    typealias T = Y
    var v:T

    init() {
    }

    func g(val:X) {
        val.f(val: v) // compiler says "Cannot invoke 'f' with an argument list of type '(val:Y)'
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` is the associated type of the placeholder type `X`, so you reference it as `X.T`. Example:

```
class B<X: P> {
    var v: X.T

    init(v: X.T) {
        self.v = v
    }

    func g(x: X) {
        x.f(val: v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's got it!